# CSS Horizontal sub-menu issue

Tags: css, submenu

I am so desperate because of one mistake in my code and I am not able to figure it out. I googled   few hours, I tried everything, but I really don't know, what to do.

```
    <div id='navi'>
     <ul class='level-1'>
        <li class='level-1'><a href='url'>HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class='level-1'><a href='odkaz'>ITEM 1</a>
            <ul class='level-2'>
                <li class='level-2'><a href='odkaz'>SUB ITEM 1</a></li>
                <li class='level-2'><a href='odkaz'>SUB ITEM 2</a></li>
                <li class='level-2'><a href='odkaz'>SUB ITEM 3</a></li>
                <li class='level-2'><a href='odkaz'>SUB ITEM 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='level-1'><a href='odkaz'>ITEM 2</a>
            <ul class='level-2'>
                <li class='level-2'><a href='odkaz'>SUB ITEM 5</a></li>
                <li class='level-2'><a href='odkaz'>SUB ITEM 6</a></li>
                <li class='level-2'><a href='odkaz'>SUB ITEM 7</a></li>
                <li class='level-2'><a href='odkaz'>SUB ITEM 8</a></li>
                <li class='level-3'><a href='odkaz'>SUB-SUB ITEM 1</a></li>
                <li class='level-3'><a href='odkaz'>SUB-SUB ITEM 2</a></li>
                <li class='level-3'><a href='odkaz'>SUB-SUB ITEM 3</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class='level-1'><a href='odkaz'>ITEM 3</a>
            <ul class='level-2'>
                <li class='level-2'><a href='odkaz'>ITEM 9</a></li>
                <li class='level-2'><a href='odkaz'>ITEM 10</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
     <li class='level-1'><a href='odkaz'>ITEM 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
```

this is css:

```
  #navi{
  width: 1100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #1c1c1d; 
}

#navi ul{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}

#navi li{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#navi li.level-1{
  float: left;
}

#navi li.level-1 a{
  display: block;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #aca4a4;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navi li.level-2 a{
  color: #aca4a4;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#navi ul.level-2{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
z-index: 2; 
}

#navi li.level-3 a{
  color: #aca4a4;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#navi ul.level-3{
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
z-index: 2; 
}

#navi li.level-1:hover ul.level-2{
  display: block;
  background-color: #25203d;
}

#navi li.level-1:hover{
  background-color: #25203d;
}
```

I don't know how to separate level 3 from level 2. If I put another ul directly under sub item 8, or used this:

```
#navi li.level-2:hover ul.level-3{
  display: block;
  background-color: #25203d;
}
```

the sub-sub menu (sub-sub item 1, 2 and 3) appears when I hover over sub item 5, but it should appears when hovering sub item 8. My menu is almost ready and I am afraid I have to start from the start now :(. Because of this one last mistake I did somewhere. Can you help me where put another ul or how to hover right, please?

And I also don't know how to force sub-sub menu to appears on the right from sub-item, I can only see it under the sub-item :(.

I found this http://cssmenumaker.com/ and I used a template but to change everything, it could take hours :(. Again :(. So it would be great, if someone could help me with my current code :).

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure whether you wanted the sub-sub menus to open down or to the side. This code will make them open sideways, since that seems to be the most common design.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BPah6/1/)

Nest the sub-sub items the same way you did the sub-items.

```
    <li class='level-1'><a href='odkaz'>ITEM 2</a>
        <ul class='level-2'>
            <li class='level-2'><a href='odkaz'>SUB ITEM 5</a></li>
            <li class='level-2'><a href='odkaz'>SUB ITEM 6</a></li>
            <li class='level-2'><a href='odkaz'>SUB ITEM 7</a>
                <ul class='level-3'>
                    <li class='level-3'><a href='odkaz'>SUB-SUB ITEM 1</a></li>
                    <li class='level-3'><a href='odkaz'>SUB-SUB ITEM 2</a></li>
                    <li class='level-3'><a href='odkaz'>SUB-SUB ITEM 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='level-2'><a href='odkaz'>SUB ITEM 8</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

In the CSS, make level 2 visible if either the corresponding level 2 li (which wraps the level 3 ul) *or* the level 3 ul itself is hovered over.

```
#navi li.level-2:hover ul.level-3, ul.level-3:hover {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #25203d;
}
```

The CSS above also contians some things to make the level 3 list display next to the level 2 item that opened it. I just have arbitrary pixel values in there for now. To make it work reliably, you'll have to set a fixed width for the level 2 dropdowns, and then set the `left:` based on that width.

You'll also have to set the position of the level 2 li to something other than static, so that the position:absolute of the level 3 ul will be based on it. (Position:absolute makes the position relative to the first parent of the element that has a position other than static.)

```
#navi li.level-2:hover {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```